# Zend Framework: How to do unit testing in case of remote API calls

Tags: zend-framework, integration-testing

I'm writing some integration tests for a big Zend Framework app of mine, using `Zend_Test`.  But I'm stuck knowing how to write tests for a few of my controllers that utilize a custom-built web API.  I am aware of `Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase`, which the ZF manual indicates could be helpful here, but I find the documentation to be really sparse.

How can I write my tests without having them call the remote server?  Best practices?  If `Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase` is called for, then how can I use it?  Here's a typical test method I would want to use this in:

```
class FooControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    public function testMyNiftyFooPage() {
        $this->dispatch('/foo'); // a page that calls a remote API

        $this->assertQueryContentContains('h1', 'Hello World');
        // other assertions, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: What does that remote call do?  Is it important that you know what the response is in the test result?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850452/how-to-unit-test-calls-to-google-api), especially the comment from @Marcin to my answer in which he recommends checking out how the framework's own unit tests handle remote calls.

Comment: +1 David -- I never thought about looking through ZF's own unit tests.  Thanks.

Comment: Calvin -- The remote call pulls in some data from a remote server, which the page needs to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate the logic that handles the remote calls in a class, have your controllers accept an instance of it (this is called dependency injection) and [mock](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html) it for the tests.

This is how testing is usually done - if you're writing a rocket launcher software you should not be launching a nuclear bomb every time your tests run.

Comment: Thanks Emil.  Looks like I'll have to forgo the $this->dispatch() call and manually do the test using Mock objects like you said.